# how many epochs needed for 68000 input frames for CNN + LSTM acrhitecture?

Tags: python, neural-network, conv-neural-network, lstm

i'm trying to train my neural network. it aims is to predict video quality. i am using VGG16+LSTM networks, but the VGG16 is not trainable. the total of trainable parameters are 700,000.
i have three questions:

1. is enough 700,000 trainable parameters for training the 68000 input frames?
2. is it essential to train vgg16?
3. how many epochs needed for getting the best resaults?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been into machine learning in a while, but my understanding is that:

1. depends, but the only way to find out is to train it and look for over/underfitting
2. depends on the network layout. It might also be useful to bypass some information around the VGG16, in case the VGG16 hides some of the information you actually need about 'video quality'
3. depends. You wouldh have to split your data into a training and a test set in order to find that out.

As most things in machine learning and especially deep learning the answers aren't obvious and depend heavily on the problem and the exact network layout. There will be much trial and error involved.

The most important takeaway, I think, is to have two (or even three) different datasets for the training/validation/test step, so you can answer those questions yourself.

For more information, read the wikipedia entry about [splitting your datasets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Training,_validation,_and_test_sets).

Answer (score 0):

You start with one and see what impact it had.
Even one epoch will take long and getting the error takes also a bit of time.